# StreamReader Exception The Given Path Is Not Supported

Tags: c#, streamreader

A while ago I wrote some code that read in a CSV file. This was working fine and I haven't touched it since. I have gone back to test it again and all of a sudden an exception is thrown on this line:

```
using (StreamReader readFile = new StreamReader(sFilename))
```

Exception states "The Given Path Is Not Supported"

sFilename is a valid file with the full path to it. It is the SAME file I was using for testing before and is a valid CSV text file.

Why could this have suddenly stopped working? This was working only a few days ago and I haven't changed it.

Comment: What is the value (fullpath) of sFileName?

Comment: The exception is The Given Path Is Not Supported as mentioned in the title. The fullpath is "C:\\test\\filename.csv". This exactly the same string that was being passed when this line of code worked just fine.

Comment: check permissions on the file and its containing folder

Comment: Permissions are fine and haven't changed since last time I tried it.

Comment: Are you sure you are setting `sFilename` correctly? Try with `Path.Combine`, I don't think the exception points to anything but an error in the path.

Comment: Yes the path is fine. I've double checked even though it is the same code exactly as what worked a few days ago. Exactly the same code, same path, same file.

Comment: Every time I think "nothing has changed since it last worked", there's always something that has changed.  Software doesn't change on it's own; if something that worked before isn't working now, something changed.  the *type* of the exception would be helpful.

Comment: Run Process Monitor while your app tries to access `c:\test\filename.csv`, which will hopefully tell you a few things:  either your app *isn't* hitting the expected path, or if your app is finding the correct path, then Process Monitor will give the error code.  Possibly something in your environment has changed even if your app hasn't.